# Why the output of this 'C' code is like this?

Tags: c, memory

I have following C code:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
int main() {

int a[4] = {1,2,3,4};

int b[4] = {1,2,3,4};

int n = &b[3] - &a[2];

printf("%d\n", n);

return 0;
}
```

Why the value of `n` is -3? I don't have a pure explanation for that. How can the difference between the addresses of the variables be a `-3`? And why it is exactly `-3`?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

While the C standard does not define the behavior when you subtract pointers to elements in different arrays, what seems to have happened is that your compiler put `b` in memory just before (at a lower address than) `a`. Thus, the memory layout looked like:

```
+------+------+------+------+------+------+------+------+
| b[0] | b[1] | b[2] | b[3] | a[0] | a[1] | a[2] | a[3] |
+------+------+------+------+------+------+------+------+
```

Given this memory layout, `&a[2] - &b[3]` is +3 because `a[2]` is three elements later in memory than `b[3]`. Then `&b[3] - &a[2]` is -3 because `b[3]` is three elements earlier in memory than `a[2]`. (Note that simple pointer arithmetic like this that does not conform to the C standard can break because the compiler may perform various optimizations or because address arithmetic is complicated on some architectures. The C standard does not just not define the result of the subtraction; it does not define the behavior of the program at all once an undefined subtraction is performed.)

Many C implementations put objects on a stack (if they have automatic storage duration, rather than static, allocated, or thread), and it is common for the stack to start at a high memory address and grow toward lower addresses. So, if the compiler is simply allocating space for objects in the order you declare them (this is not to be expected generally; there are a number of reasons to do fancier things), then it effectively would put `a` on the stack first, then decrease the stack pointer, and then put `b` on the stack, so `b` ends up at a lower address than `a`.

Incidentally, the result of subtracting two pointers has size `ptrdiff_t`, which is not necessarily `int`, so it ought to be printed with `printf("%td\n", n);` rather than `%d`, and `n` should be declared with `ptrdiff_t n;` rather than `int n;`. The `ptrdiff_t` type is defined in the `<stddef.h>` header.

Comment: @TypeIA: Updated.

Comment: Apparently I passed a test by up-voting this, but in an effort to undo that goodness, you might want to back off a bit on the “C Standard Idolatry”.  The C Standard is inferior to  historical practice, and the psalms of  undefined behaviour  a thin rationale to cheat at benchmarks  Thank you clang.  C is primarily a systems language, and deals effectively with systems oriented constructs.  If you don’t like systems languages, use C++, that is why it exists.

Comment: @mevets: How many C compilers guarantee the layout of objects declared as `a` and `b` are declared in the question? Even if a compiler guarantees that pointer arithmetic works as addresses in a flat address space, compilers generally do not guarantee how objects are laid out on the stack. So one cannot rely on `&b[3] - &a[2]` being −3, and this needs to be stated in the answer. Additionally, optimization is becoming increasingly aggressive in compilers, so a compiler that did support general address arithmetic might still recognize that `&b[3] - &a[2]` is undefined and subject to optimization.

Answer (score 4):

The behaviour of the code is *undefined*.

Pointer arithmetic, including the subtraction of two pointers, is *only* valid for pointers to elements within the same array. (For this purpose you can set a pointer to one past the end of an array, and an object counts as an array with one element.)

Answer (score -3):

With C calling convention (on x86) local variables are pushed onto the local stack and as a result are adjacent in memory.

In this case the two arrays are relatively adjacent in memory. (The exact value can be effected by things like byte/word/qword alignment)

The end result you'll get a consistent value, that can be predicable given your build environment/options.

Comment: Calling conventions specify what a program must put on the stack and in registers when calling a routine. They do not govern how a routine manages its own local objects. The result cannot be expected to be easily predictable, as a compiler might rearrange local objects to suit purposes of space efficiency, performance, or other reasons. Optimization might even eliminate the objects from memory entirely.

Comment: Sorry but you cannot say one is going to get a consistent/predictable value when the behaviour is unpredictable.  Case the compiler had arranged a different memory allocation or placed more data in between the two arrays, you'd had gotten a different value.  Optimizing can make things even worse.  Cannot accept your answer as valid.